# Gcloud CLI Identity-Aware Proxy management

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, app-engine-flexible, google-iap

Is it possible to manage **Identity-Aware Proxy** in Google App Engine Flexible, only by using `gcloud` CLI?

I need to have dynamic domains with different app versions (eq https://0-2-1-1-dot-myproject-prod.appspot.com/ or later https://0-2-1-1.myproject.com/). I know how to set a fixed domain (eg. https://myproject.com/ or https://new.myproject.com/) in IAP but this is a basic scenario.

I would like to have a possiblity to use wildcards in IAP (like. https://*.myproject.com/) to set it up in advance to all dynamic domains, but AFAIK it is rather not possible.

Second option is to add a new domain together with a new version, tag or even review in DEV project in my CD pipeline, using `gcloud` CLI, but until now I didn't find any subcommand to do this.

So, can I add a new domain to IAP from CLI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately:

- It's not currently possible to add a domain from the CLI.
- Wildcards aren't supported.

You *can* add specific additional domains from the API Manager > Credentials screen in Cloud Console. We have some more detailed instructions down at the bottom of https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/app-engine-quickstart .

(We've heard loud and clear from App Engine users that the interaction between IAP and App Engine versions isn't great due to the redirect URL issues and are working on a solution, but that's the best option today.)

--Matthew, Cloud IAP team